# How to get dtype column names

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I use genfromtxt to create a `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("test.txt",dtype=None,delimiter=',',names=True)
```

This results in:

```
array((500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 504, 504), dtype=[('ColumnName1', '<i8'), ('ColumnName2', '<i8'), ('ColumnName3', '<i8'), ('ColumnName4', '<i8'), ('ColumnName5', '<i8'), ('ColumnName6', '<i8'), ('ColumnName7', '<i8')])
```

What I would like to know is how to retrieve the column names? `data.dtype` doesn't seem to be getting me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to be working, as to the results i get with `data.dtype.names`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data=np.array((500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 504, 504), 
    dtype=[('ColumnName1', '<i8'), ('ColumnName2', '<i8'), 
    ('ColumnName3', '<i8'), ('ColumnName4', '<i8'), ('ColumnName5', '<i8'),
    ('ColumnName6', '<i8'), ('ColumnName7', '<i8')])
```

gives

```
>>> data.dtype.names
('ColumnName1', 'ColumnName2', 'ColumnName3', 
   'ColumnName4', 'ColumnName5', 'ColumnName6', 'ColumnName7')
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.dtype` is *exactly* where you should be looking. Where else? You want:

```
data.dtype.names
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `names` method

Comment: Nor was I. It took me all of `help(data.dtype)` and 5 seconds to find it, though.